# valence desire 2 learn profile image upload

Tags: image, upload, profile, desire2learn, valence

I'm trying to upload an image to my profile using the api but I'm getting a Unknown: NOT_FOUND 404 error. the call I am using is /d2l/api/lp/1.0/profile/myProfile/image, I am passing the content type, length and filename (profileImage). I'm passing the image as a dataStream. I've reduced the size of the image as well. Any ideas?

also here is part of my CallAction code orginally gotten from the Getting Started example

```
public void CallAction(ID2LUserContext userContext, int retryAttempts, string url, byte[] data, string method = "")
    {
        Uri uri = userContext.CreateAuthenticatedUri(url, method);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.Method = method;

        if (method.Equals("PUT") || method.Equals("POST"))
        {

            request.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            //request.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"profileImage\"; filename=\"profileImage.jpg\"");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, compress");
            //request.Headers.Add("X-Upload-Content-Type", "image/jpg");
            //request.Headers.Add("X-Upload-Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
            //request.Headers.Add("X-Upload-File-Name", "profileImage");
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream(); 
            dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            dataStream.Flush();
            dataStream.Close();
        }
```

}

Also when I run a get to retrieve my photo it also returns a 404 error.

Comment: Is your upload [RFC1867](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1867.html) compliant?

Comment: Your code scrap makes it look like you're providing the Content-Disposition and 'image/jpeg' Content-Type headers to the HTTP POST headers, when those should be attached to the *part* header.

The HTTP POST headers should contain a Content-Type of 'multipart-form/data' (with a boundary), and the *part* should contain the file data (with boundary) that has the 'Content-Disposition' header (form-data) and 'Content-Type' (of the image content-type, in your case 'image/jpeg').

It's not clear to me that your code is doing this.

Answer (score 0):

We have tested this call against our test instances here, and it does work. Here's what the HTTP packet headers look like for a valid test call (from a call formed with the python `requests` module):

```
{ 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/1.2.3 CPython/3.3.2 Darwin/12.4.0',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=716acd781e224902854e6845bc62f653',
  'Content-Length': '117886',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress' }
```

to this URL:

```
https://somelms.edu/d2l/api/lp/1.0/profile/myProfile/image?
x_a={appId}
&x_c=Lz3PDTaUgG46cMF3CajAsiiGzz0C6u5QTLieAmbONZ0 
&x_b={userId}
&x_d=7sSqbce1_ictuNAs80n01h0jSI0YxxKbPM01W7f49a0
&x_t={timestamp}
```

with a body that looks like this (note the *part headers* in this body, that characterize the content of the single part in the body that contains the image data):

```
--716acd781e224902854e6845bc62f653
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profileImage"; filename="profileImage-student.png"
Content-Type: image/png

{image bytes here}

--716acd781e224902854e6845bc62f653--
```

Comment: Thanks, I added some code and more information to my original post as I am still having problems.

Comment: See my comment to your question; I've amended this answer as well to be more clear about which headers go where.

Answer (score 0):

This code should fix your problem:

```
public static void UploadFilesToRemoteUrl(byte[] profileImage, ID2LUserContext userContext, string accion)
    {
        //Reference:
        //action = "/d2l/api/lp/1.3/profile/" + profileIdentifier + "/image";

        //profileImage = the profileImage of user read from disk:
        /*
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(pictureLocalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        Byte[] img = new Byte[fileStream.Length];
        fileStream.Read(img, 0, Convert.ToInt32(img.Length));
        fileStream.Close();
        */

        var uri = userContext.CreateAuthenticatedUri(accion, "POST");
        string boundary = "bde472ff1f1a46539e54e655857c27c1";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" +
        boundary;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, compress");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        request.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Constantes.UsuarioProxy, Constantes.PasswordProxy, Constantes.DominioProxy);

        Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" +
        boundary + "\r\n");


        string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary +
        "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profileImage\"; filename=\"profileImage.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg;\r\n\r\n";

        byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formdataTemplate);
        memStream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);

        //escribo el array de byte de la imagen
        memStream.Write(profileImage, 0, profileImage.Length);

        byte[] boundaryClose = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--");
        memStream.Write(boundaryClose, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        StreamReader readerReq = new StreamReader(memStream);
        string stringReq = readerReq.ReadToEnd();

        request.ContentLength = memStream.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        memStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
        memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        memStream.Close();
        requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            string responseValence = reader.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you give some explanation of what your code does? We generally try to avoid having posts containing just code. You could do this either in the body of your message or in comments throughout your code :)